# How should we deal with duplicate users?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Poor Bernard seems to have two profiles. Is there any way we can un-split his personality and merge the two profiles into one or should he just delete one of them?

Comment: Relevant page in the Help Center: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Profiles can be merged by the user themself by using [the "contact us" form](/contact) at the bottom of any page. In most cases the user should be able to take care of the whole merge process on their own, but on some occasions they might need to go through a process carried out by a staff member responding to support tickets — which can result in a merge, or not.

That being said, there isn't much *you* can do if you see other users have duplicate profiles, short of potentially leaving a comment pointing them to the "contact us" form if the user says something that hints at the duplicate profiles being unwanted.

If the user doesn't mention anything like that, I wouldn't bother them with it because having duplicate profiles, in and of itself, is not a problem — having duplicate profiles only becomes a problem if you use them to be able to perform actions the system wouldn't allow you to perform from a single profile (voting for your own posts, posting if the system has blocked you from doing so, circumventing a suspension, etc.).

Comment: Thanks he's back to one user thank to your help. Much appreciated!